# Getting the width of an action bar tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I want to have an action bar with tabs and a viewPager for the body in order to be able to scroll the tabs. 
I also want to have a view to "underline" the selected tab, and have it move when I scroll the viewPager.
Is there a way to get the size of the tab? Since I'm different devices the tabs may be scrollable I can't just divide the size of the screen by the amount of tabs.. 
I want it to be something like this:

[image]